# Show the unique conversion rate from visits to purchases of item A by day

Tags: sql

Need to show the unique conversion rate from visits to purchases of item A by day

See expected output vs actual output
[image]

Currently 'visitors' line is wrong need it to show counts from visits instead of counts from sales

```
SELECT
    t1.day
    ,count(distinct t1.user_id) as visitors
   ,count(distinct t2.user_id) as converts
FROM visits t1
LEFT JOIN sales t2
    on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
        AND t1.day = t2.day
WHERE t2.item_name = ‘A’
GROUP BY t1.day
ORDER BY t1.day
```

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.  What YOU mean by "conversion rate" is not obvious, so a clear explanation of the calculation is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    t1.day
   ,count(distinct t1.user_id) as visitors
   ,count(distinct t2.user_id) as converts
FROM visits t1
  LEFT JOIN sales t2
    on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
   AND t1.day = t2.day
   AND t2.item_name = ‘A’
GROUP BY t1.day
ORDER BY t1.day
```

If you apply the filter by t2.item_name in the where clause, you are removing the left join logic. You just need to move that filter to the left join, in order to apply it before joining the tables.